# Producing table from MATLAB command window output and exporting to Overleaf Latex

Tags: tables, overleaf, matlab

Is there any way to produce a table from this MATLAB output in command window and exporting to Overleaf Latex?[image]

Comment: You can of course copy-paste it to a `tabular` environment and add `&`  and ```\\``` manually. But I guess you're after something more automatic? If so, do you have the values in variables, or are they just printed in the terminal?

Comment: @Torbjørn T. They are printed in the command window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities. If you cannot modify the Matlab code to somehow either make variables or write the table to ready `tabular` code, I suppose they all involve copy-pasting the table from the command window.

So the most basic way is to just add the necessary `&` and `\\` manually. So if you have e.g.

```
NS   Nt  max error  rate
4  500  5.29e-3
8  500  1.49e-3  1.027
...
```

turn it into

```
NS &  Nt & max error & rate \\
4 &  500 & 5.29e-3
8 & 500 &  1.49e-3 & 1.027
```

and put it in an appropriate `tabular` environment. Two examples are shown in the code example below. If you have a text editor that can do column-wise editing (such as Notepad++, Kile, Visual Studio Code), these edits become a a bit simpler.

If you want something a bit more automatic, you can use for example the `pgfplotstable` package. Copy the table into a `\pgfplotstableread`, and modify it a bit: change `max error` to `{max error}`, remove the empty line, and add `{}` in the empty cell. This is also demonstrated in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

% Note two things here:
% - The column name with two words have { } around the two words
% - A {} is placed in the empty cell
\pgfplotstableread{
  NS   Nt  {max error}  rate
  4  500  5.29e-3  {}
  64  500  1.49e-3  1.027
}\matlabtable

\begin{document}

The most basic table:

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    NS &  Nt & max error & rate \\ 
    4  & 500 & 5.29e-3 \\
    64  & 500 & 1.49e-3 &  1.027 
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

With siunitx for number parsing and printing, and booktabs for rules:

\begin{tabular}{S S S[table-format=1.2e1] S}
\toprule
    {NS} &  {Nt} & {max error} & {rate} \\ \midrule
    4  & 500 & 5.29e-3 \\
    64  & 500 & 1.49e-3 &  1.027 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Semi-automatic with pgfplotstable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
% add horizontal rules around first and last rows
every head row/.append style={
  before row={\toprule},
  after row={\midrule}
  },
every last row/.append style={
  after row={\bottomrule}
  },
% change how the numbers in the rate column is printed, to use three decimals
columns/rate/.style={/pgf/number format/precision=3}
]\matlabtable
\end{document}
```

## Addendum

Example with captioned tables. To read in multiple tables, use different macro names.

Note that `\matlabtable` was just a random name I came up with, you could have used `\pgfplotstableread{..}\fred` and `\pgfplotstableread{..}\george`. Just don't use the name of an existing macro or environment. For example, `\pgfplotstableread{..}\table` would break the `table` environment, because `\begin{table}` actually does `\table`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

% the following settings in \pgfplotstableset will apply to all tables made with \pgfplotstabletypeset
% If you prefer to add the settings to each individual table, like in
% my previous example, that's entirely up to you.
\pgfplotstableset{
% add horizontal rules around first and last rows
every head row/.append style={
  before row={\toprule},
  after row={\midrule}
  },
every last row/.append style={
  after row={\bottomrule}
  },
% change how the numbers in the rate column is printed, to use three decimals
columns/rate/.style={/pgf/number format/precision=3}
}

% reading in data:
% Note some things here:
% - The column name with two words have { } around the two words
% - A {} is placed in the empty cell
% - Use different macro names for the different tables
\pgfplotstableread{
  NS   Nt  {max error}  rate
  4  500  5.29e-3  {}
  64  500  1.49e-3  1.027
}\matlabtableA

\pgfplotstableread{
  NS   Nt  {max error}  rate
  8  500  9.29e-3  3.14466
  128  500  6.49e-3  1.027
}\matlabtableB


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Stuff}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\matlabtableA}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Other stuff}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\matlabtableB}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to align the table to the centre and also caption it ?

Comment: @Rhombus https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/tables#Captions.2C_labels_and_references for example.

Comment: I think I got my question wrong. I wanted to know if there is a way to align and caption the table created using pgfplotstable package. I want to read multiple outputs from command window. How do I label them individually? Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Rhombus There's no difference ... Put the pgfplotstabletypeset where you otherwise would place the tabular environment.

Comment: I'm putting everything from \pgfplotstabletypeset [ ..... ] \matlabtable under \begin table...\end table to label and caption it but getting error. Moreover, I'm not understanding if I read 2 tables from MATLAB command window using pgfplotstableread, how do I show them separately because there is no way to label them? Coul you please modify your code to illustrate this point?

Comment: @Rhombus See update.